# Unable to render a table with rowSpan inside my SPFx React web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts

Inside my ReactJs SPFx web part i want to build a table as follow:-

```
<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i tried this code which will build a `<td>` inside the map iteration (currently i have 3 items to map), but it raised syntax errors mainly that the `<tr>` does not have a matching end tag:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';

import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';

export interface INews {
    recentNews: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featuredNews?: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featured: boolean;
}

export default class SingleNews extends React.Component<INews, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INews> {
        return (
            <><table>
                {this.props.featured
                    ? this.props.recentNews.map((post,index) => {
{index === 0 ? 
<tr>
<td rowSpan={2}>
<a
    className={styles.singleNews}
    href={post.link}
    key={post.Title}
>
    <div
        className={styles.singleNews__image}
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
    />
    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                {post.date}
            </span></div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>

            <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                {post.Title}
            </h2>



            {post.likes ? (
                <div
                    className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                >
                    <span
                        className={
                            styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                        }
                    >
                        <Icon iconName='Like' />
                        {post.likes}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                        {post.coments}
                    </span>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    </div>
</a></td> : null }

{index === 1 ? 

    <td >
    <a
        className={styles.singleNews}
        href={post.link}
        key={post.Title}
    >
        <div
            className={styles.singleNews__image}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
        />
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                    {post.date}
                </span></div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
    
                <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                    {post.Title}
                </h2>
    
    
    
                {post.likes ? (
                    <div
                        className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                    >
                        <span
                            className={
                                styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                            }
                        >
                            <Icon iconName='Like' />
                            {post.likes}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                            {post.coments}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a></td></tr> : null }
    {index === 2 ? 
        <tr>
        <td >
        <a
            className={styles.singleNews}
            href={post.link}
            key={post.Title}
        >
            <div
                className={styles.singleNews__image}
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
            />
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                    <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                    <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                        {post.date}
                    </span></div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
        
                    <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                        {post.Title}
                    </h2>
        
        
        
                    {post.likes ? (
                        <div
                            className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                        >
                            <span
                                className={
                                    styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                                }
                            >
                                <Icon iconName='Like' />
                                {post.likes}
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                                {post.coments}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </a></td></tr> : null }                 
                    })
                    
                                : null
                      }
            </table></>
        );
    }
}
```

Any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, considering each of those long, complicated `<td>` sections is the same, I would pull all of that out and make it its own component where you pass in the individual post and the rowspan (could be 1 or 2) as props:

NewsTableCell.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';
import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';

export interface INewsTableCellProps {
    post: ISingleNewsProps;
    rowspan: number;
}

export default class NewsTableCell extends React.Component<INewsTableCellProps, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INewsTableCellProps> {
        
        const { post, rowspan } = this.props;

        return (
            <td rowSpan={rowspan}>
                <a
                    className={styles.singleNews}
                    href={post.link}
                    key={post.Title}
                >
                    <div
                        className={styles.singleNews__image}
                        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
                    />
                    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__label}>{post.Featured}</span>
                            <span className={styles.singleNews__content__info__date}>
                                {post.date}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.singleNews__content}>
                        <div className={styles.singleNews__content__info}>
                            <h2 className={styles.singleNews__content__info__title}>
                                {post.Title}
                            </h2>
                            {post.likes ? (
                                <div
                                    className={styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions}
                                >
                                    <span
                                        className={
                                            styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes
                                        }
                                    >
                                        <Icon iconName='Like' />
                                        {post.likes}
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                        <Icon iconName='ActionCenter' />
                                        {post.coments}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            ) : null}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
        );
    }
}
```

Then, in your other component, when you build the table, don't try and map over the posts in the return part, map over them before the `return` build an array of the new `td` / `NewsTableCell` components, and use that array in the `return` part:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';
import NewsTableCell from './NewsTableCell';

export interface INews {
    recentNews: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featuredNews?: ISingleNewsProps[];
    featured: boolean;
}

export default class SingleNews extends React.Component<INews, {}> {
    public render(): React.ReactElement<INews> {

        const newsTableCells = this.props.recentNews.map((post, index) => {
            return (
                <NewsTableCell
                    post={post}
                    rowspan={index === 0 ? 2 : 1}
                />
            );
        });

        return (
            <table>
                {this.props.featured ?
                    <>
                        <tr>
                            { newsTableCells[0] }
                            { newsTableCells[1] }
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            { newsTableCells[2] }
                        </tr>
                    </>
                    : null
                }
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

That's going to keep your code much cleaner and easier to understand, and you won't run into the issue you're having where you have to break the HTML structure of the `tr`s in your loop causing the error you're having.

Comment: thanks a lot .. your code worked perfectly for me..